# New line within bootstrap pop-over

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

What is a seemingly trivial problem is causing me quite the headache...
I am trying to simply move to a new line after each piece of information. I have tried `'\n'`, `<br>`, using `<br>` within a `<p>` and done extensive research online with no success.

**My Code:**

```
<td>
     <button type="button" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed"
            data-placement="top"
            title= "{{ x.Recipient.Name + x.Recipient.Email_Address + x.Recipient.Job_Title + x.Recipient.Department + x.Recipient.Office }}"
            onmouseenter="$(this).tooltip('show')">
                   {{ x.Recipient.Name }}
     </button>
</td>
```

The pop-over works well with no issues, but the information is squeezed together, and I want each section separated on its own line. Thanks for any help in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use Enter:

```
<td><button type="button"
    class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed"
    data-placement="top"
    title= "{{ x.Recipient.Name 
        x.Recipient.Email_Address 
        x.Recipient.Job_Title 
        x.Recipient.Department 
        x.Recipient.Office }}"
    onmouseenter="$(this).tooltip('show')">
    {{ x.Recipient.Name }}
</button></td>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sn4795ug/

Comment: It does - if you hover over the button you see the multiline-popup. But you're right I could remove it.

Comment: I question whether or not I can call myself a programmer after such a mistake.